# Can you travel to the US 6 days before your H1B visa expires?

Tags: visas, usa, h1b-visas

I'm currently working in US, with VISA valid uptil end of Sept.
I've applied for extension, and the petition is under review atm.

There is a requirement that may need me to go out of US and come back for a week in mid-Sept.

Would that be a problem while returning?

Comment: shouldn't be any problem IMO

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

This shouldn't be a problem if you have maintained your status in the past (Not overstayed the I-94 period). The CBP can question your intentions and doubt if you will overstay (if you have done so in the past).

Also note that if your employer doesn't file for an extension within the requisite time frame when your status expires, you will be willfully violating immigration laws.